# Large gap between menu and content - How do I get rid of this?

Tags: css

I run a small link aggregator site for my colleagues at: http://techlinks.neocities.org/index.html

I've just adapted the site using pure.css framework, so I can use drop down menus. However this seems to have introduced a large gap between the nav menu and content.

I have tried setting the margins and padding to zero on the affected elements , tried negative padding values and tried different positioning properties for the nav bar.

Nothing I've tried gets rid of the gap however.

What is creating the gap and how can I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code here, so that we can identify the bugs!

Comment: The 'pure-menu-item' has height: 100%, which makes the dropdown 100% height.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `height: 100%` from the `.pure-menu-item` element.
It's located in the `pure-min.css`.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain the problem with my answer please? This is exactly why there is such a large gap.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your code by pressing F12 button. You have set the height of `.pure-menu-item` as `100%` and that's the reason for this large gap. Try setting it to smaller value like `10%`. That should do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the site to use a customised version of pure.css, with the change suggested (removed the height property), instead of using the CDN link.

The gap is gone. Many thanks Paul.

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help!